# Have "copy" work correctly in suggested edit markdown diffs

Tags: feature-request, bug, suggested-edits, markdown-rendering

I was doing a suggested edit review on Stack Overflow, and found an edit where the Question OP had accidentally put an edit in response to an answerer in the answer instead of the question.  I copied the edit, which included code, from the markdown diff, and rejected the edit.  I then went into the question to edit the copied text into it, but found that none of the line returns copied at all, so it was a jumbled mess.

Could we please have `copy` work correctly on the text in the markdown diff section of the suggested edit?

Comment: This may be one of those rare meta posts where it'd be appropriate to have two required tags: [feature-request][bug].

Comment: My last update to the x86 tag wiki (which I've improved several times before) got rejected (by 3 reviewers with no sign of answering any asm or x86 questions, who didn't leave any comments...).  Now I have to manually copy the non-controversial parts into another edit.  This sucks, a lot.